# How to replace a variable number of instances in a string?

Tags: postgresql

A front end WYSIWYG editor in our application has been producing strings with gobs of `<p>` tags in the editable string.  Every time the records were updated, the `<p>` tags would double.  How can I fix the data, reducing n number of consecutive `<p>` tags in the string with a single one?

Change this:

```
<p><p>Hello, world
```

or this:

```
<p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p>Hello, world
```

to this:

```
<p>Hello, world
```

Comment: Please provide an example text and the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with using regular expression.
Example:

```
select regexp_replace('<p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p>Hello, world', '(<p>)\1{1,}', '\1', 'g');

Result: 
<p>Hello, world
```